# Retrieve JSON file from JS trough php

Tags: ajax, json, customization

I know this question has been asked probably 100 times, but i couldn't find a convincing answer for my situation.

Here is my understanding:

On PHP side:

```
var obj= json_encode ($array);
```

so then `$array` is available on admin-ajax.php in Json format,

On JS side:

```
$.ajax({
   url: ajax_url,
   data: {
          action: 'myphpfunction',
          nonce:mynonce,

         },
    dataType: "json",
    success:  success action
});
```

Where i'm stuck is that my source is not an array nor a string,but a json file so all data are stored in json format already on the sever side.

Which means `json_encode` is not useful here as my source is already json 
and an `echo` or a `print` will not make the data available on the admin-ajax.php but on the current page i'm running on.

So this where i'm stuck, how can i pass this json file to the front end, is there a way to make it available so a simple HTTP GET could be done like that for instance (using jQuery)?

`$.getJSON('./path/to/my.json',data,callback);`

PS: context i'm migrating a static HTML website which include google map (with data) to a WordPress environment.

So basically, my issue is on the PHP side where my data are already JSON formatted and needs to be push to the front-end (JS).

Hope the question it's clear enough

Thanks for any input which could help me better understand how this is working.

Kindly

**EDIT:**

Here is what i'm doing for now but it doesn't clean method to me, is there a better way to do this?

**PHP:**

```
wp_register_script('google_map', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/map.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
wp_localize_script('google_map', 'mdu', array(
     'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'mdu' ),
     'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
wp_enqueue_script('google_map');


function json_gmap(){ 

    $get_file  = file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/config/mapdata.json'); 
    $json_to_array = json_decode($get_file,true);
    die (json_encode($json_to_array));

}
```

add_action('wp_ajax_json_gmap', 'json_gmap');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_json_gmap', 'json_gmap');

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
   url: mdu.ajax_url,
   data: {
          action: 'json_gmap',
          nonce:mdu.nonce,

         },
    dataType: "json",
    success:  this.mapDataLoaded(self, maparea)

});
```

Matth.

Comment: In your example, how were you planning to pass obj back to the client? Basically just do that with your file: my PHP is rusty but it's essentially just set the output content type and encoding as a header then echo the file contents, then stop if that's not done implicitly.

Comment: That is my interrogation in fact, for now the only idea i found is to 'json_decode' the local json file on the server side to an array then 'json_encode' the array to make it available to admin-ajax.php on wp ajax interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced this is the cleanest way to do it but at least it work until I find something more efficient:

```
function json_gmap(){

  $get_file  = file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri() . '/data/my.json');
  $json_to_array = json_decode($get_file,true);
      die (json_encode($json_to_array));

}
add_action('wp_ajax_json_gmap', 'json_gmap');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_json_gmap', 'json_gmap');
```

Basically I decode my Json file to an array and the re-encode it to have it available in admin-ajax.php.

Any improvement is welcome :D

Thanks

Matth